# jquery hide element when no interaction occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element pop up in the screen on page load and it hides after 5 seconds. I'm trying to create logic where it'll hide if the user doesn't interact with the pop up, and if user does interact, it'll keep it shown, and if user leaves the element, the timer starts again to hide.

```
<div id="popup">
  Some popup
  <input type="email" placeholder="enter email" />
</div>

<div id="popup-button" style="display:none;">
  button to open the popup
</div>

// on load, 5 seconds starts
var goTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
  $('#popup').css("display","none");
  $('#popup-button').css("display","block");
  }, 5000);
  goTimeout;


// when mouse enter's popup element and/or user types in input
// should turn off the setTimeout
$(document).on("touchstart click mouseenter keyup", "#popup", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e);
  clearTimeout(goTimeout);
});


// when user mouse leave's the popup the timer starts again, but
// if user is still focused within input field, don't start until
// user clicks outside of the element
$(document).on("mouseleave", "#popup", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e);
  clearTimeout(goTimeout);
  goTimeout;
});
```

Was wondering if someone can help me with the logic, not getting it to work the way I like to

Comment: What if every user interaction launch a new goTimeout function and increments it by 5 seconds or something? I'm sure if I'm making my self clear but I hope you get it

Comment: goTimeout; -> goTimeout();

Comment: So, you've basically got it, except that in your code `goTimeout` is a number, not a function. You might want to use `function hideAfterFive() { return setTimeout(...); }` and then `goTimeout = hideAfterFive();` whenever you want to start the timeout again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

goTimer isn't a function but you're trying to call it like it is one at the end of your mouseleave section. Make a function that creates / starts the timer and you'll be good to go. Like this:

```
var goTimeout;
function myTimer() {
  goTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#popup').css("display", "none");
    $('#popup-button').css("display", "block");
    }, 5000);
}
myTimer();
```

Then just change the last line of your mouseleave section to be:

`myTimer();`  instead of `goTimeout;`

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkocm8vj/) to check out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOM elements like onmouseover, onmousedown, etc.

Also, the timeout declared at the end seems to be the error, it's more of a variable or count, than a function.

You can have something like,

```
Gotimeout=5;
clearTimeout(goTimeout);
```